# how to publish photos on facebook wall from an external ( django + python) application

Tags: django, facebook

I want to publish my photos from django application to the facebook wall, i use photos.upload method I am not using graph API. but I am not able to publish it even i took permissions to publish photos as well but still not working......

Please help me how could i achieve it please give me some sample code that will help me

Comment: if you posted the relevant parts of your code, then maybe someone might be able to help.

Comment: I am using this code :

    photo_path = open("C:/xxxx/apps/local/main/media/photologue/photos/xxxx.jpg","r")
    request.facebook(
        method="photos_upload",
        args={
            "photo": photo_path,
            "uid":   '1253548155'
        }
    )

But this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can publish photos by using this it work form me...

request.facebook(

```
        method = "stream_publish",
        args={
        'message' : "Test Message with Picture",
        'attachment' : simplejson.dumps({ 'media': [
                {'type': 'image',
                 'src': 'http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/funny-pictures-your-cat-is-bursting-with-joy1.jpg',
                 'href': 'http://xxxx/xx/5157d6da/'}]}),
        'uid' : 'uid'})
```

Comment: Where is request.facebook coming from?